# Trying to get sql query parameter and automate script

Tags: java, mysql, selenium, testing, automation

I am using selenium and java.

1. Every time when I execute my test it has to create new log in credentials.
2. I enter usernames (every time it is created randomly)
   This is my method to create a unique username:

   ```
   String username=’’ ’’ +(int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   String emailID=”USER”+username+”@gmail.com”;
   driver.findElement(by.id(“userNameID)).sendKeys(emailID);
   system.out.println(emailID);
   ```

   It creates a unique username.
3. After it will ask for verification code, it is coming from DB and I have to pass it in “verification textbox”.
   I have my JDBC Connections,
   Usually when I already know my username 
   I use:

   String query=”Select SecretCode from createlogincode where 
      username=qacustomer@gmail.com”;
      String secretCode=rs.getString(1);
      System.out.println(“Verification Code is ”+secretCode);
      driver.findElement(by.id(“secretcode”)).sendKeys(secretCode);

and this methods works perfectly.
But with creating random usernames, I am not able to write a correct query to pass and get verification code. Is there is any method to store the new username then pass it into the query?
I was doing:

```
     String query=”Select SecretCode from createlogincode where username= 
 +emailID”;
```

but this is absolutely incorrect.